# How 1 address can create 14 inputs in output transaction to 1 direct address?

Tags: transaction-input

Check this address 1NM3apKLeDGKiFsd6gu1o4nh52efi38iEv

The reason of this extremely high fee because of 14 inputs

But why 1 address generate 14 inputs instead 1?

Answer (score 3):

When funds are sent to an address, the funds are locked into a UTXO (Unspent Transaction Output). When you want to spend funds, you create an input that references a specific UTXO and satisfies the corresponding locking script. It doesn't matter whether the UTXOs were sent to the same or to different addresses. Every UTXO has to be spent explicitly and separately. There is no efficiency gain to spending multiple UTXOs received to the same address in one transaction, each still needs its own input to be spent.

Comment: What about inputs, why it separated to 14 different shards?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

> But why 1 address generate 14 inputs instead 1?

For much the same reason that buying a loaf of bread might involve handing over 14 different coins from your pocket to make up the price of one loaf.

You don't have a pocket smelter to melt down a pocketful of small coins and create a single big coin marked 38.62 Roubles. If you did, the shopkeeper would probably throw you out without handing over the loaf of bread.

Comment: but you don't need to put coins consistently one by one to shopkeepers hand, that's why 1 address can be 1 input, no matter how many outputs it recieved before